# Google app engine or query (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can anyone share your approach for doing a 'or' query in app-engine?

Let say I have

```
class A_db_model(db.Model):
 valueA = db.ListProperty(basestring)
```

in valueA I have

```
aaa
aaa, bbb
bbb
ccc
```

I would like to return result of if the valueA match 'aaa' or 'bbb' and return not duplicated result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this?

```
A_db_model.all().filter('valueA IN', ['aaa', 'bbb'])
```

or the equivalent GQL:

```
GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM A_db_model WHERE valueA IN :1', ['aaa', 'bbb'])
```

Comment: Note that the datastore can't actually do this kind of query; this syntax results in 2 queries being done and the results merged.  Using long lists of values for the IN condition is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Yep. In fact, due to how list properties work, you wind up doing `NxM` comparisons in `N` queries.

Answer (score 2):

The two main problems with @Amber's approach is that it is slow as it basically runs a query for each value behind the scenes and it maxes out at 30 values to query for. I just wrote a blog post about this question. It explains the best scalable way to basically do an OR query with app engine. You can use a separate entity to make this happen. See the post for details.

http://tornblue.com/post/11310830291/app-engine-how-to-do-an-efficient-or-query