# Run sql like "OR" query on appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I run the equivalent of this query:

```
"select * from users where username='john' or email='john@email.com';
```

on appengine? I know appengine doesn't support the "OR" but has "IN" just not sure how to use it for such a query.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714972/google-app-engine-or-query-python) question gives an example of using 'IN' as an 'OR' equivalent.  However, as noted in the comments, GAE will treat 'IN' like multiple queries and is generally a bad idea, especially when querying on many list values.

Your best bet is often to perform the separate queries yourself and combine them programmatically.

EDIT: As pointed out, using an IN filter won't work anyway for your specific example.

Comment: Won't work anyway for this case; you can only use IN for queries where you're searching for multiple values in the same property, not different properties.

Comment: I agree with you! I think the less worse solution is 2 requests!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in one query in Appengine. You can do two querys and combine the two results.You should do something like this to achieve the above query

```
  result_1 = users.all().filter("username = ","john").fetch(100)
  result_2 = users.all().filter("email = ",'john@email.com').fetch(100)
  results = result_1.extend(result_2)
```

Comment: Abdul Kader, i tried the code and got this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: results = result_1.extend(result_2)
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: Try changing to a keys only query (ie users=users.all(keys_only=True)), this will return list objects, which can be extended (and shouldn't give you a NoneType error).  Once you've combined the results you can query the entities themselves using 'results = users.get(results)'.

Comment: Also - you may want to consider not using 'users' as your entity name, since there already a 'users' module in GAE.

Comment: @jwesonga. Just try adding fetch to it................as kevin suggested change your model name

Comment: @KevinP changing to a keys only query had no effect, I keep getting the "results=result_1.extend(result_2)
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'extend'" error @AbdulKader adding fetch also had no effect, the error I got with that is:result_1=users.filter("auth_username = ",self.request.get("username"))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: @jwesonga, sorry the problem was with me, Now try the edited one.. I posted the last one without testing